# qt5-default package missing in Hirsute repo

Tags: package-management, 21.04

When installing iriunwebcam-2.4.deb, it said `iriunwebcam : Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable`

After searching I found out that the package qt5-default is available upto groovy repo but not hirsute. Is there any way to install it in 21.04?